# Make JPG business cards in Photoshop from Excel list

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, batch-processing, microsoft-excel

I have a large list of  names & phone numbers (in one column) in Excel and also have a master PSD file that I'd like to have each one saved into as separate files. I also have the filenames of the new files in another column. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Yes.  Instructions here: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html - but the file names will be generated automatically using a base filename. As far as I know, I don't think there is any way to name the files based on a field in the data itself.  Perhaps this could be done via scripting?

Comment: @BillyKerr i dont think it matters much renaming consecutive files by a csv file is easy enough

Comment: how would you do that? can filename be a variable in the data set?

Comment: theyre not consecutive btw...custom filenames